# Xcode Link error:Linker command failed with exit code 1:ld -bundle_loader can only be used with -bundle

Tags: xcode, hyperlink, bundle, loader

There was a link error when I build my unit test code, the error message shows:

ld: -bundle_loader can only be used with -bundle
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)